# Codeigniter Select JSON, Insert JSON

Tags: json, codeigniter, select, insert, routes

I have very simple users database: user_id, user_name, user_email

My model this:

```
class Users extends CI_Model {
private $table;
private $table_fields;
private $table_fields_join;

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    $this->table = 'users';
    $this->table_fields = array(
            $this->table.'.user_id',
            $this->table.'.user_name',
            $this->table.'.user_email'
    );
    $this->table_fields_join = array();
}

function select(){
    $this->db->select(implode(', ', array_merge($this->table_fields, $this->table_fields_join)));
    $this->db->from($this->table);

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        return $query->result();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function insert($data) {
    $data = array(
       'user_name'  => $data['user_name'],
       'user_email' => $data['user_email']
    );

    $this->db->insert($this->table, $data);
}
```

My controller this:

```
class Users extends CI_Controller { 

function __construct(){
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->model('users');
}
public function select(){
$data['query'] = $this->users->select(); 
$data = json_encode($data['query']);
echo $data;
}
public function insert($json){
  $data = json_decode($json);
  $this->users->insert($data);
  }
}
```

And this is my routing.php:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Welcome';
$route['users'] = 'users/select';
$route['users/insert/:(any)'] = 'users/insert';
```

I would like that 127.0.0.1/users/select give json.
Example: [{"user_name":"user1","user_email":"user@user.de"}]

This JSON insert my table: 127.0.0.1/users/insert/[{"user_name":"user1","user_email":"user@user.de"}]

But my code is not working. :-(

Comment: What exactly is the error? Can you post the error log?

Comment: Error? No error. The code is not working. I think that the routing is wrong. Because I rename select function to index and default_controller = Users, that select is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to return json object in response, so it's required to set `json` type in response header. As given [here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/output.html)

```
public function select(){
  $data['query'] = $this->users->select(); 
  $this->output
    ->set_content_type('application/json')
    ->set_output(json_encode($data['query']));
}
```

It is required to encode part as below for insert part. so you can use this generated url to call your insert.

```
site_url('usres/insert/'.urlencode('[{"user_name":"user1","user_email":"user@user.de"}]'));
```

your insert route should be as

`$route['users/insert/:(any)'] = 'users/insert/$1';`

your insert method should be updated as

```
public function insert($json){
  $json = urldecode($json);
  $data = json_decode($json);
  $this->users->insert($data);
  }
}
```

Comment: The routing is not working. The $route['default_controller'] = 'welcome' is OK. If I rename select function to index, and I change welcome to Users $route['default_controller'] = 'users'  then select is OK. But $route['users/select'] = 'users/select'; and $route['users/insert/:(any)'] = 'users/insert/$1'; is not working. 

My .htaccess file this:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]

And I change config.php:
$config['index_page'] = '';

Comment: Delete .htaccess file and try to do with index.php/users

Comment: Have you added $config['index_page']='index.php' back ?

Comment: Already I tested, but not working. First I not used htaccess this project and not changed $config['index_page']='index.php'.

Comment: The problem is resolved. I found this: http://www.arifulhaque.com/codeigniter-htaccess-and-index-php-issues-solution/

My problem was AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All.